# URI naming schema for API with virtual resources + boolean parameter

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, api-design

I am designing my first web API, and I'm having difficulties settling on a naming scheme for the URIs.

The API does not address actual resources, instead it is being made to accept a query, run some logic on the query string, accumulate respective results from different other APIs, perhaps run some logic on the accumulated result again, and return the result.

I have started to set up the single `GET` that exists as follows (returns "result" object in JSON).

```
api.example.com/query?string=foo&otherparam=bar
```

However, I'm unsure whether this follows best practices.

### Problem 1

I'm starting to think that in order to follow best practices for API design, the endpoint name shouldn't actually be `query`, it should be `result`, but as I don't actually have resources, this is a bit counterintuitive.

So **question 1** would be: Is `api.example.com/result` the better endpoint name?

### Problem 2

This refers to semantic URLs. Consider the following example from [Wikipedia: Semantic URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Structure).

*Non-semantic URL*:
`http://example.com/products?category=12&pid=25`

*Semantic URL*:
`http://example.com/products/12/25`

*Semantic URL adapted for my case*:
`http://api.example.com/result/foo/bar`

This is very logical and works well if you have actual resources that you look up. In my case, however, the parameter *string* is the query string, and the parameter *otherparam* is a boolean describing a property of the query string.

So **question 2** is really: **If the answer to question 1 is "yes"**, what should a semanticized URL in my case be:

1. `http://api.example.com/results/foo/bar`?
2. `http://api.example.com/results/foo?otherparam=bar`?

(`results` should be plural I guess as it's describing the list of possible results.)

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not think `result` is a good endpoint name. Besides, `result` is super generic and doesn't imply anything.

When I design APIs, the endpoints can either be resources or **actions on resources**

- `https://api.example.com/accounts/1/authorize` - the resource here is `accounts` and the action is `authorize`
- `https://api.example.com/search` - the resource here would be the entire platform so any resource could be returned and the action is `search`

So is there any type of resource you can attach to the `query` action? Or it sounds like this type of endpoint would suit you better?

```
https://api.example.com/logic/run
```